# How to receive RTP stream and extract audio? (Java)

Tags: java, audio, udp, rtp, codec

## Intro

Hello, myself and a few coworkers have run out of ideas on properly receiving audio over RTP and then extracting the audio stream and hope someone out there can point us in the right direction.

### Background:

Audio traffic is sent over the network via a multicast address and port. This traffic is RTP over UDP. We need to extract the audio out of the packet and pack it into a different UDP packet and send it somewhere else.

Our program currently does a few things so far, it takes the packets received on the multicast address and copies the data into a buffer. We then remove the first 12 Bytes of data as we understand that is the RTP header.

After the Bytes are removed, we use JAVA JMF library to convert it to a InputStream and a AudioFormat is applied to it. Then it is sent to a SourceDataLine for local playback to verify audio quality.

### Problem:

When the audio is played back it sounds very bad. I can make out the audio but there is a lot of noise and cracking/popping. We can not figure out why it sounds so bad.

We have verifed the RTP audio quality using VLC. It plays back perfectly so we know it is something with our code. The audio is being encoded in G.711 PCMU and can be played back using VLC or Wiresharks built in RTP stream analyzer. We have messed with the AudioFormat settings but still can not get the audio to play cleanly.

Our only thought is that the audio is being sampled too much and adding a ton of noise or that is not formatting correctly. I have included links to some files that may be useful if trying to recreate our setup. We use bittwist to send the packets captured in the wireshark file.

Captured Audio Playback that sounds bad:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1f4XiNELRVFUsMXgokNwUSnkVO10Ysq_T

G711 Wireshark Packet Capture:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bZ54KH-KXeHd8CKQEVAU5vawoSiGWZFS

Wireshark Audio Extract with good audio:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-ZLXcoPesqsHdniiNqcCwUoZX50PP_mG

## Java Code

Credit: RustedBrain/MusicHole

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream;
AudioFormat adFormat;
TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
AudioInputStream InputStream;
SourceDataLine sourceLine;


private AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
    float sampleRate = 8000.0F;
    int sampleInbits = 8;
    int channels = 1;
    boolean signed = true;
    boolean bigEndian = false;
    return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleInbits, channels, signed, 
bigEndian);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new VUServer().runVOIP();
}

public void runVOIP() {
    try {
        MulticastSocket serverSocket = new MulticastSocket(22202);
        InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("239.1.1.1");
        serverSocket.joinGroup(group);
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[10000];
        while (true) {
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new 
        DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + receivePacket.getAddress().getHostAddress() + " " + receivePacket.getPort() + " " + "Packet Size: " + receivePacket.getLength());
        try {
            byte temp[] = receivePacket.getData();
            byte[] filteredByteArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(temp, 12, receivePacket.getLength() - 12);
            byte audioData[] = filteredByteArray.clone();
            InputStream byteInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(audioData);
            AudioFormat adFormat = getAudioFormat();
            InputStream = new AudioInputStream(byteInputStream, adFormat, audioData.length / adFormat.getFrameSize());
            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, adFormat);
            sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
            sourceLine.open(adFormat);
            sourceLine.start();
            Thread playThread = new Thread(new PlayThread());
            playThread.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

class PlayThread extends Thread {

byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];

public void run() {
    try {
        int cnt;
        while ((cnt = InputStream.read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length)) != -1) {
            if (cnt > 0) {
                sourceLine.write(tempBuffer, 0, cnt);
            }
        }
        //  sourceLine.drain();
        // sourceLine.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

Hopefully I have explained our problem enough to where someone can find where we messed up and help us get back on track.

Thank you,

Austin

Comment: I was just looking up RTP on wikipedia. It says that the header (which you are discarding) has a *MINIMUM* of 12 bytes. That implies to me that it can vary in size. Also, the header contains sequencing info and time stamps. UDP does not maintain the order of the signals. Are you handling the ordering and not compensating correctly for missing audio data?

Comment: Can you dump the pcmu data from the rtp payload and share it.

Comment: Make sure the setting for PCMU audio data playback is correct. ( if your PCMU dump is proper)

Comment: the constructor of AudioFormat that you're using sets the encoding to Linear PCM.  You need to use one of the other constructors that takes an AudioFormat.Encoding as a parameter and use AudioFormat.Encoding.ULAW

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat.html#AudioFormat(javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat.Encoding,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20boolean)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem ?